# How to create a second page once first page is filled in C# printed note?

Tags: c#, printing

[image]

As you can see the data gets overflown away from the page.

How do I make it so that once the page has too many items for 1 page the rest of the products are printed over to a second page.

This is my code.

```
 private void btnSaveOrderAndPrintReceipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // NEED TO ADD EDITING ORDER FUNCTIONALITY HERE

        tblOrder newOrder = new tblOrder();

        //newOrder.CreateNewOrderTableInDBandFill(productsObjList, Convert.ToDecimal(TransactionTot));

        //Printing
        printPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument;

        printPreviewDialog.Size = new Size(1365, 727);
        printPreviewDialog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();

        //Return back to main menu

        frmMainMenu nextForm = new frmMainMenu(dataTransferToOtherForms.LoginDetails.ManagerAccount);

        nextForm.Show();

        this.Close();

    }

    private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        /*A note with all the order details is printed for the kitchen staff
         */

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Daddy John’s restaurant", new Font("Forte", 25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(200, 30));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Kitchen Staff Note", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(200, 70));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Order taken by: " + dataTransferToOtherForms.LoginDetails.UserName, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(200, 100));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Order belongs to table: " + dataTransferToOtherForms.TableName, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(200, 125));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------" + DateTime.Now, new Font("Courier", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 150));

        //Displaying Date Time on the note
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ordered  On: " + DateTime.Now, new Font("Courier", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 200));

        //Constants for the products
        string font = "Courier";
        int ycord = 300;
        int xcord = 25;
        //
        foreach (ProductSelected product in productsObjList)
        {
            string prodQnty = product.QuantityOrdered.ToString().PadRight(50);
            string prodDesc = product.Description;
            string prodPrice = "£" + product.Price.ToString();
            string prodLineQntyDesc = prodQnty + prodDesc;

            //Displaying the Quantity + decription of product.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(prodLineQntyDesc, new Font(font, 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(xcord, ycord));

            //Displaying the price
            e.Graphics.DrawString(prodPrice, new Font(font, 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(xcord + 700, ycord));

            ycord = ycord + 20;
        }

        //Adding you know
        ycord = ycord + 40;

        //displaying total price of receipt.
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total to pay:".PadRight(30) + Convert.ToString(transactionTot), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(xcord, ycord));

    }
```

Comment: Just ckeck your ycord value in the loop and create a new page at a certain threshold...?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - _create a new page_ which is done by setting `HasMorePages = true` and leaving the `PrintPage` event.

Comment: @Lucero   I am not sure how to do that. After 44 loops I want to create page number 2.

Comment: You need to keep track of the print progress externally, and after 44 items stop printing on the page and set the HasMorePages property on the event object true. The Print page event will be called again for the second page etc.